# Why is my Ubuntu server running many tmux server processes?

Tags: server, tmux, top, ps

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4B. I'm viewing top to monitor what's going on and it is showing at the moment 11 'tmux: server' processes. Tmux is running, showing one window containing four panes. `tmux ls` is showing only one tmux session and I am the only user on this system.

Top is looking like this:

```
        PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 442735 forkbeard    20   0    2112     92      0 R  26.3   0.0 158:41.99 sh
 528026 forkbeard    20   0    9744   3284      0 R  26.3   0.0  20:52.28 tmux: server
 437265 forkbeard    20   0    9744   3284      0 R  24.7   0.0 173:13.35 tmux: server
 416513 forkbeard    20   0    2112     92      0 R  24.0   0.0 265:19.36 sh
 518289 forkbeard    20   0    2112     92      0 R  24.0   0.0  36:45.63 sh
 463927 forkbeard    20   0    9744   3284      0 R  23.7   0.0 118:41.86 tmux: server
 429208 forkbeard    20   0    9744   3284      0 R  23.4   0.0 206:13.66 tmux: server
 442671 forkbeard    20   0    9744   3284      0 R  23.4   0.0 158:40.05 tmux: server
 518605 forkbeard    20   0    9744   3284      0 R  23.4   0.0  36:02.78 tmux: server
 442526 forkbeard    20   0    9744   3284      0 R  23.1   0.0 159:29.68 tmux: server
 454131 forkbeard    20   0    2112     92      0 R  23.1   0.0 135:06.35 sh
 486599 forkbeard    20   0    9744   3284      0 R  23.1   0.0  81:16.72 tmux: server
 498747 forkbeard    20   0    9744   3284      0 R  23.1   0.0  62:09.51 tmux: server
 486415 forkbeard    20   0    9744   3284      0 R  22.8   0.0  81:28.65 tmux: server
 534318 root         20   0  398672  11260   1964 R  22.8   0.1  10:38.05 rsync
 528130 forkbeard    20   0    9744   3284      0 R  22.4   0.0  20:45.50 tmux: server
```

I have noticed this before on this machine and a reboot fixes it - but that's not a great solution. Killing the processes doesn't work, even as root; it doesn't give me an error but the process just keeps running.

If I'm listing the processes using `ps` I can also see the processes (first output line added for readability). What I find curious is the processes' start times: I am pretty sure I did not start any tmux sessions during the night.

```
root@rpi:/home/forkbeard# ps aux | grep [t]mux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
forkbeard    295509  0.6  0.0   9876  5984 ?        Ss   Aug12   7:45 tmux
forkbeard    429208 33.2  0.0   9744  3284 ?        R    Aug12 209:02 tmux
forkbeard    437265 30.6  0.0   9744  3284 ?        R    Aug12 176:00 tmux
forkbeard    442526 29.5  0.0   9744  3284 ?        R    Aug12 162:18 tmux
forkbeard    442671 29.4  0.0   9744  3284 ?        R    Aug12 161:28 tmux
forkbeard    463927 27.5  0.0   9744  3284 ?        R    Aug12 121:29 tmux
forkbeard    486415 25.1  0.0   9744  3284 ?        R    01:38  84:14 tmux
forkbeard    486599 25.1  0.0   9744  3284 ?        R    01:38  84:05 tmux
forkbeard    498747 24.1  0.0   9744  3284 ?        R    02:43  64:57 tmux
forkbeard    518605 22.4  0.0   9744  3284 ?        R    04:19  38:50 tmux
forkbeard    528026 21.4  0.0   9744  3284 ?        R    05:22  23:39 tmux
forkbeard    528130 21.4  0.0   9744  3284 ?        R    05:22  23:34 tmux
forkbeard    549554  0.0  0.0   7000  3072 pts/2    S+   07:10   0:00 tmux att
```

What's going on?

/edit:

`pstree` gives me this:

```
├─tmux: server─┬─bash───sudo───su───bash───watch
│              ├─bash───top
│              ├─bash───sudo───su───bash───pstree
│              ├─bash───sudo───su───bash───rsnapshot───rsync───rsync───rsync
│              ├─bash───sudo───su───bash
│              └─11*[tmux: server]
```

Comment: You might want to use `pstree` to inspect the parent and child processes of those `tmux` processes.

Comment: Added the pstree result